# Python Pandas merge 3 columns of lists in to a single column

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 columns with keywords that have been derived through different algorithms.

the data is something like this

**product    desc          keywords1               keywords2                              keywords3**

productX, "blah blah", [iot, internet, cloud], [cloud, internet, energy management], [internet of things, cloud, internet]

How do I merge the 3 keyword column in to a single one and also remove any duplicates, for example the keywords "cloud" should only be stored once?

Comment: kindly post sample dataframe with expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `set()`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[['a', 'c']], 'c2':[['a', 'd']]})
df['c3'] = (df['c1'] + df['c2']).apply(set).apply(list)

df
```

```
    c1      c2      c3
0   [a, c]  [a, d]  [d, a, c]
```

Comment: Just to add a little information about "why your answer is the best approach", pandas are mostly utilized when vectorization is used. Using for loop or any other row-wise approach will slow down the process and also does not provide the benefit of using pandas.

Comment: Using this seems to also add empty fields in to the list... how do make sure that it doesn't add them, or how do I remove them from the final list?

Comment: what do you mean by empty fields? Like ['', 'a']?

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a function to the data frame that does set intersection across the three columns.

```
df['updatedKeywords'] = df.apply(lambda row: set(row['keyword1']) & set(row['keyword2'] & set(row['keyword3']), axis=1)
```

If you had a lot of columns to intersect you could extend it:

```
columnsToIntersect = ['keyword' + str(i) for i in range(numberOfKeywordColumns)]
df['updatedKeywords'] = df.apply(lambda row: set.intersection(*[set(row[x]) for x in columnsToIntersect], axis=1)
```

Finally, you could also use [pandas.DataFrame.aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html), though it may be overkill for this sort of task.